# TortoiseSVN icon overlays and network shares/mounts

Tags: performance, tortoisesvn, smb, network-share

Enabling TortoiseSVN icon overlays on network drives [slows down](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovlonlylocal) the whole system.

What is the size of, and is there anything that can be done to mitigate this impact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tortoisesvn-dev/dCXz8jODeRE/GFzuBsOGcq0J) to TSVN's lead developer [Stefan Küng](http://tortoisesvn.net/stefan_kueng.html):

> the drive type is checked last when the cache 
>   determines whether to show an overlay for a path. If the path is in the 
>   'allowed paths' list, then the drive type isn't even checked so it 
>   should be faster. And of course the state of the checkbox shouldn't 
>   matter at all.